# Telerik RadEditor rendering issues

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radeditor

Telerik RadEditor control doesn't appear to be rendering properly in IE 8/9 web browsers as the buttons from its toolbar are all rendered as list items.

There's no such issue with all other browsers. The Telerik.Web.UI dll version is 2012.1.411.40. I'd have thought IE 8/9 would be supported.

So is there any workaround/solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical IE browser issue for older versions. There's some limit on how many CSS files can be include in one web page.

As was discussed in this post, [Internet Explorer CSS limits](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/10-05-03/internet-explorer-css-limits.aspx), the max number of css files can be included in IE 8/9 is 31.

So some of the workarounds are:

- upgrade IE browser to the latest version
- bundle and combine css files

Answer (score 0):

Or add a [RadStyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.html) to the page.